# Upload files to asp.net page from WPF

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf

I have an asp.net page that can upload files to a server, but I need to read all folders in a CD-ROM and upload all of them to this page. I made a program in WPF but I always receive a 401 error (Unauthorized), how could I achive this?

I have this code to upload the file:

```
foreach (var archivoMS in ArchivosMS) {
            var ruta = Helper.Route + 
                "?action=save" +
                "&id=" + archivoMS.Id + 
                "&idType=" + archivoMS.IdType +
                "&name=" + archivoMS.Name;
            FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(archivoMS.NameWithRoute);
            HttpContent fileStreamContent = new StreamContent(fileStream);
            using (var client = new HttpClient()) {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Helper.Route );
                using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent()) {
                    formData.Add(fileStreamContent, archivoMS.Name, archivoMS.Name);
                    var response = client.PostAsync(ruta, formData).Result;
                    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: are you in control of the asp.net website? I have found it works easier to write a wcf service to handle the file request and then in wpf zip the files, and upload them in one bing bang (or loop on each file)

Comment: Yes, the website is inside our intranet server.

Comment: Does your asp.net system require authentication?

Comment: We use windows authentication.

Comment: and under what username does your wpf app run as http error 401 is authentication error

Comment: It's using my username, but I'm in the administrator's group on the server.

Comment: not sure if this will help, but this is the tut I used to upload files http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166763/WCF-Streaming-Upload-Download-Files-Over-HTTP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a handler with useDefaultCredentials to your httpclient. It may not be sending your credentials at all.

HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);